# Why is the 'sudo' password different than the 'su root' password

Tags: linux, sudo, password, su, administration

On my personal machine, I often type `sudo` in front of certain commands in order to accomplish administrative tasks.  I had hoped to avoid doing this throughout the day, by typing `su root` and providing the same password I usually do for `sudo`.  However, the two passwords are not the same(I don't know how to log in to `su root`).  Is running a command with `sudo` different than logging in with `su root` and running the same command?

I think `sudo` and `su root` are the same, because when I type `sudo whoami`, I get `root`, as opposed to just `whoami` where I get my user-name.

Comment: I came across this older thread because it was linked as related to a question I asked.  The answers are very informative but leaves a question.  On a personal machine (one user), how do you get a different password for root depending on whether you use sudo or su root?  Isn't there a single root password, defined when Linux is installed?

Comment: @fixer1234 As explained [in John1024's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109945/306760), when you use `sudo`, the system asks for _your password_ to verify your identity, then checks `/etc/sudoers` to see if you're allowed to run sudo. When you use `su`, the system requires you to input _the password of the user you're switching to_. (I know this is now a _very_ old question, but I wanted to add a clarification for the benefit of future viewers.)

Comment: @anonymoose, this question was about the OP's personal machine.  Typically, when you install Linux on your own machine, you would know if you gave root a different password from your regular user.  The question indicates that the OP was surprised to find out that root had a different password.

Comment: @fixer1234 The OP might not have set a root password to begin with. [Ubuntu's installer doesn't ask for a root password](https://askubuntu.com/a/347825/840992), and I'm sure that some other distros don't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Contrary to what their most common use would lead you to think, `su` and `sudo` are not just meant for logging in (or performing actions) as root.

`su` allows you to switch your identity with that of someone else. For this reason, when you type `su`, the system needs to verify that you have the credentials for the target user you're trying to change into.

`sudo` is a bit different. Using `sudo` allows you to run certain (or all, depending on the configuration) commands as someone else. Your own identity is used to determine what types of commands `sudo` will run for you under someone else's identity: if you're a trusted user (in the sense that the sysadmin trusts you), you'll be allowed more free rein than, say, an intern. This is why `sudo` needs to verify your own identity rather than that of the target user.

In other words, trying to `su` to someone you're not is like attempting to charge your purchases to a stolen credit card while using `sudo` is like selling your friend's car by legal proxy.

As for what you were trying to do, just `sudo su root`, or even more simply `sudo su` and type your regular user password. This would roughly amount to replacing your friend's credit card credentials with your own using the legal proxy they gave you :). It of course assumes the `sudo` configuration allows you to run `su` with escalated privileges.

Also, systems that come pre-configured with `sudo` access typically have the root account disabled (no root password), you can enable that using the `passwd` command after becoming root via `sudo su`.

Comment: For home user, would you recommend setting root password in addition to having user with privileges (As in `sudo`)?

Answer (score 4):

It is configurable* but, by default, "sudo" asks you for your password.  It is just trying to make sure that it is you, not someone using your keyboard while you were getting coffee.

By contrast, "su root" asks you for the root password.

---

*If targetpw in /etc/sudoers is false (default), "sudo" asks you for your password.  If it is true, then "sudo" asks you for the password of root or, if you specified some other user with the "-u" option, the password of that user.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` is used to temporarily escalate user permissions to root level, whereas `su root` is used to create a new shell with root as a user;

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of some newcomers into this search, there is a simple method to go into root until you exit:

```
     sudo -iE
```

Will keep you interactive and keep your environment but now, as root.