# How does the OS know that a command needs sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo

1. When you run an executable, sometimes the OS will deny your
   permission to.   For example running `make install` with the prefix
   being a system path will need `sudo`, while  with the prefix being a
   non-system path will not be asked for `sudo`. How does the OS decide
   that running an executable would require more privilege than a user
   has, even before the program does something?
2. Sometimes, running a program will not be denied permission, but the
   program will be able to do more things if it is run with `sudo`. For
   example, when running `du` on some system directory, only with
   `sudo` it will be able to access some directory. Why does the OS not
   deny permission of running such a program, or friendly notify more privilege is preferred, before the program can run?
3. Is it true that  whenever `sudo` works, `su` will also work, and
   whenever `su` works, `sudo` will also work? or with `su`, a user can do
   more than with `sudo`? How does the OS decide when `sudo` works, and
   when `su` is needed?

Comment: Has this question been answered for you, or would you like more information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Sometimes the "Permission denied" message is due to filesystem permissions denying you write access, for example. The executable/tool simply checks if it the filesystem grants you enough permissions to do what you're about to do and throws an error if it's denied by the filesystem. Other times, the tool itself will check your user ID before allowing you to continue using it.
2. When you run a program with `sudo` you are running it under some other user's name. If that user is "able to do more things" than your user and the `sudo` configuration allows you to do these things on the other user's behalf then yes, `sudo` will allow you to do more things. This is not necessary, though. If you just tack `sudo` on at the beginning of the command line, you're actually `sudo`ing as `root`, so typically you're able to do more things than a mere mortal.
3. Most definitely not. To use `sudo` you need to supply your own user password and then you're allowed to do some things on the target user's behalf. To use `su`, you need the *target user's password* and if you have it, you become that target user as far as the system is concerned and can do anything that user can do.

**See also**

- [Why is the 'sudo' password different than the 'su root' password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109944/26909)

Comment: Thanks. Is " filesystem permissions denying you write access" = "access mode  of the file has no execution bit set for the user, which can be set by chmod"?

Comment: @Tim Actually it = "access mode of file has no _write_ bit set for the user". And yes, this can of course be remedied by `chmod` provided you're either the owner of the file or `root`.

Comment: Does whether sudo is needed, completely and solely depend on  whether the execution bit is not set for the user? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147052/674

Comment: @Tim Obviously you need the execute bit to be able to run the executable in the first place.

Comment: @JosephR. Not obvious. `chmod 400 hello && /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./hello` produces a nice "Hello, World!" output.

Comment: @DougO'Neal I would say that _your_ way is the non-obvious one. But then I guess "obvious" is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 25):

For the purposes you have described, the OS doesn't decide whether you need sudo to initially *run* the program. Instead, after the program starts running and then tries to do something that is not permitted by the current user (such as writing a file to `/usr/bin` to install a new command), the OS prevents the file access. The action to take on this condition is up to the program; `make` stops running but `du` will proceed to the next file/directory after printing a message.

The `su` and `sudo` commands are two different ways of running a program with root privileges. They may differ in minor details such as the contents of the environment when starting the new program, depending on options used. The OS does not need to decide when one or the other might work.

Answer (score 7):

`su` and `sudo` are privileged programs.  `su` changes (after successful authentication) the real and effective user and group id to that of the user you `su` to.  Thus, `su` is similar to `login`.  Note that `su` can be used to change to any user, not just root.  `sudo` also changes the real and effective user and group ids.  Up to this point `su` and `sudo` are similar (but unrelated), beyond that they are very different.

With `su`, you need to know the target's password, and once you authenticated, you can do whatever you want as that user.  The use of `su` can be restricted by setting `SU_WHEEL_ONLY` in `/etc/login.defs`.  If it is set, only users in the group `wheel` may use `su`, otherwise it is not restricted.  Apart from that, `su` is all or nothing.

`sudo` is completely different with respect to that.  With `sudo` you can define quite complex policies in `/etc/sudoers` on what the sudoer (the user who calls `sudo`) is allowed to do.  For instance, you can define policies where certain users may run only certain programs with certain privileges, while other users may run other programs with other privileges.

One of the striking features of `sudo` is that you can configure it such that a user has to authenticate himself with *his own password* (instead of that of the target).  Thus, `sudo` has grown very popular amongst admins, for it allows to authorize users to do only defined privileged operations without dealing out the superuser password, plus you get some degree of accountability.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** Access is determined by the user who is running application, and `sudo` runs applications as different user.

Full version:

> How does the OS know that a command needs sudo?

It doesn't know. UNIX manages permissions not on application level but on filesystem level: permissions are granted for users to access specific files. Applications then are run on behalf of user - each running process has user associated with it. That user is used to determine permissions for that application. Sudo works by running applications on behalf of other user (with permissions associated with that another user), namely `root`, the superuser.

As for your examples:

1. If user has write access to particular directory, they can `make install` into that directory. Otherwise they may have `root` do it - by using `sudo`.
2. If you cannot access files in a directory, `du` running for you cannot access it either. `root` can access virtually every file, so `sudo du` (`du` run on behalf of `root`) can access them too.

> Is it true that whenever sudo works, su will also work, and whenever su works, sudo will also work?

Yes and no. Yes, if program is *actually* run, it should behave the same under both `sudo` and `su`. However, `sudo` provides allows for more fine-grained control of who may run what by set of rules stored in `/etc/sudoers` file. `su` is more simple - if you know target user's password, you can run programs on behalf of that user.

Last note: how application handles denial of access (wherher it aborts or ignores or warns user) is up to application.

Answer (score 1):

No one has a ✓ yet, so I put together an answer that has everything I could think of.

*1   When you run an executable, sometimes the OS will deny your permission to. For example running make install with the prefix being a system path will need sudo, while with the prefix being a non-system path will not be asked for sudo. How does the OS decide that running an executable would require more privilege than a user has, even before the program does something?*

No it is not done when an executable is started. It is done when the executable tries to do something.

The Os will check file-system permissions, and capabilities (these are not covered by file-system permissions, and include reduce nice level, mknode, some low-level network stuff, kill other's processes, reboot, set time etc.). If you do not have the permissions then you can not do it. Root has full set of capabilities, including CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE (ignore file permission).

*2  Sometimes, running a program will not be denied permission, but the program will be able to do more things if it is run with sudo. For example, when running du on some system directory, only with sudo it will be able to access some directory. Why does the OS not deny permission of running such a program, or friendly notify more privilege is preferred, before the program can run?*

The OS can not know what the program will do. So it is up to the program to check permissions before it starts, and to decide what to do. It does not have to do this though.

Note: on android there is a manifest, in this the application declares what privileges it may use. The OS will kill any application that tries to use a privilege that it does not declare, and the OS does not always guarantee that a privilege can be honoured. e.g. network access may not be available.

*2   Is it true that whenever sudo works, su will also work, and whenever su works, sudo will also work? or with su, a user can do more than with sudo? How does the OS decide when sudo works, and when su is needed?*

`sudo` and `su` do roughly the samething. Some differences is environment variable handling and other such security issue avoidance. However they are both tools to allow you to become another user, and both have a default user of root.

`su` was the original tool, it requires you to enter the password of the user/group that you are changing to.

`sudo` is newer and requires, by default, for you to enter your own password, but can be configured to accept the password of the user/group that you are switching to, or no password at all. It also allows a lot of configuration, of what commands it will work with, for who, and how it will authenticate with this program for this user on this machine. There is also `sudoedit` this is part of `sudo` and can be used to allow editing as a different user and avoid the security issue of sub-shelling out of an editor (calling exec from the editor to run an arbitrary process with escalated privileges).